# WPF XAML não renderiza

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Estou tendo problema com a view só renderiza normalmente quando insiro o ResourceDictionary nos resources da mesma, mas quando insiro o ResourceDictionary nos resources do App.xaml a view em questão não renderiza não há mensagens de erro no output do Visual Studio.
Alguém já passou por esse problema e sabe como solucionar?

Conteúdo do ResourceDictionary estou alterando o estilo do controle Wizard da Telerik:

```
 <telerik:DoubleToThicknessConverter x:Key="DoubleToThicknessConverter"/>
```

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="WizardPageTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type telerik:WizardPage}">
        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Border x:Name="PART_SideHeaderBorder"
                        Grid.RowSpan="2"
                        Background="#FFFFFFFF"
                        BorderBrush="#FF333333"
                        BorderThickness="{Binding SideHeaderBorderWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource DoubleToThicknessConverter}, ConverterParameter=Right}"
                        Width="{Binding SideHeaderWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                        Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsSideHeaderVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">

                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SideHeaderPresenter"
                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding SideHeader}"
                                      TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SideHeaderTemplate}"
                                      TextBlock.FontSize="{telerik:Windows8TouchResource ResourceKey=FontSizeL}"
                                      TextBlock.FontFamily="{telerik:Windows8TouchResource ResourceKey=FontFamily}"/>
                </Border>

                <Border x:Name="PART_HeaderBorder"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{Binding HeaderBorderWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource DoubleToThicknessConverter}, ConverterParameter=Bottom}"
                        Height="{Binding HeaderHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">

                    <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock x:Name="PART_PageTitle"
                                   Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Title}"
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                   FontFamily="{telerik:Windows8TouchResource ResourceKey=FontFamily}"
                                   FontSize="{telerik:Windows8TouchResource ResourceKey=FontSizeXL}"
                                   FontWeight="Bold"
                                   Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                   Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsTitleVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>

                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_HeaderPresenter"
                                          Grid.Row="1"
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                          TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                          Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsHeaderVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                                          TextBlock.FontSize="{telerik:Windows8TouchResource ResourceKey=FontSizeL}"
                                          TextBlock.FontFamily="{telerik:Windows8TouchResource ResourceKey=FontFamily}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>

                <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_PagePresenter"
                                  Grid.Row="1"
                                  Grid.Column="1"
                                  Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                  ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                  TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                  Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                  TextBlock.FontFamily="Segoe UI"/>

                <Border x:Name="PART_FooterBorder"
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                        BorderThickness="{Binding FooterBorderWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource DoubleToThicknessConverter}, ConverterParameter=Top}"
                        MinHeight="48"
                        BorderBrush="#FF333333"
                        Background="#FFFFFFFF">

                    <ContentControl x:Name="PART_FooterContentControl"
                                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding FooterTemplate}"
                                    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="FooterTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <telerik:RadButton x:Name="PART_Help"
                Content="{Binding HelpButtonContent, Mode=TwoWay}"
                MinHeight="36"
                Margin="9,0,0,0"
                MinWidth="78"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Visibility="{Binding NavigationButtonsVisibility.HelpButtonVisibility}"
                Command="{x:Static telerik:RadWizardCommands.Help}"/>

            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <telerik:RadButton x:Name="PART_Previous"
                    Content="{Binding PreviousButtonContent, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    MinHeight="36"
                    MinWidth="78"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Visibility="{Binding NavigationButtonsVisibility.PreviousButtonVisibility}"
                    Command="{x:Static telerik:RadWizardCommands.MoveCurrentToPrevious}"/>

                <telerik:RadButton x:Name="PART_Next"
                    Content="{Binding NextButtonContent, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    Margin="8,0,0,0"
                    Visibility="{Binding NavigationButtonsVisibility.NextButtonVisibility}"
                    MinHeight="36"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    MinWidth="78"
                    Command="{x:Static telerik:RadWizardCommands.MoveCurrentToNext}"/>

                <telerik:RadButton x:Name="PART_Finish"
                    Content="{Binding FinishButtonContent, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    Margin="8,0,0,0"
                    MinHeight="36"
                    MinWidth="78"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Visibility="{Binding NavigationButtonsVisibility.FinishButtonVisibility}"
                    Command="{x:Static telerik:RadWizardCommands.Finish}"/>

                <telerik:RadButton x:Name="PART_Cancel"
                    Content="{Binding CancelButtonContent, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    Margin="8,0,0,0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    MinHeight="36"
                    MinWidth="78"
                    Visibility="{Binding NavigationButtonsVisibility.CancelButtonVisibility}"
                    Command="{x:Static telerik:RadWizardCommands.Cancel}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="WizardPageStyle" TargetType="{x:Type telerik:WizardPage}">
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource WizardPageTemplate}"/>
        <Setter Property="FooterTemplate" Value="{StaticResource FooterTemplate}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,9"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="HeaderHeight" Value="40"/>
    </Style>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="RadWizardTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadWizard}">
        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
            <Grid>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedPagePresenter" 
                                  Content="{Binding SelectedPage, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                  Visibility="{Binding Path=IsContentPreserved, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource InvertedBooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                <Grid x:Name="ContentElementsPanel" Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsContentPreserved, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:WizardPage}" BasedOn="{StaticResource WizardPageStyle}"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:CompletionWizardPage}" BasedOn="{StaticResource WizardPageStyle}"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:WelcomeWizardPage}" BasedOn="{StaticResource WizardPageStyle}"/>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadWizard}">
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource RadWizardTemplate}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF333333"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF333333"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding" Value="True"/>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Poste o código.

Comment: Ok inclui o código